# How can I remove the first character from all filenames in a folder?

Tags: windows-7, rename

I need to remove the first character (which is always "_") from all filenames in a folder.

I'm currently using this command: ren `_*.txt *.txt` But it doesn't work.

However, if I run `ren _*.txt A*.txt` it perfectly works, but it is not what I want.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

again, try powershell ;)

Run this in your desired directory:

```
get-childitem *.txt | rename-item -newname { [string]($_.name).substring(1) }
```

Explanation:
- `get-childitem *.txt` collects all *.txt-files in the actual directory.
- `rename-item -newname` renames the piped results from the get-childitem command with the string that is generated in {}
- `[string]($_.name).substring(1)` takes the filename starting after the first character

Comment: hey, it says gci is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: hm... this should work...however. gci is per default an alias for Get-Childitem - take that instead. Did you run powershell? It doesn't work if you tried that in cmd.exe (but you can start powershell.exe from within cmd)

Comment: all right, now it works. I still have a small issue, the first character is actually a ".", so I have 2 initial characters to remove "._filename.jpg" and not "_filename.jpg". Do you how to deal with the dots ?

Comment: if you want to remove the first 2 characters, just replace the (1) after 'substring' with (2). In powershell, the whole filename is treated as a string(-object), points included.

Comment: If you want to replace any part in the middle of the name (which is the same in every name), you can use `replace` instead of `substring` like so: `get-childitem *.txt | rename-item -newname { [string]($_.name).replace("old string","new string") }`

Answer (score 11):

Forget about complicated scripts for this.

`rename` is a very old and never properly completed command. 
If you do not use it properly, the result might surprise you.

For example to remove a prefix abcd from abcd1.txt, abcd2.txt, abcd3.txt etc. in order to get 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt simply use

```
rename "abcd*.txt" "////*.txt"
```

You need the same number of / as the number of initial characters you would like to remove. 
So, for your specific situation, you would use

```
ren "_*.txt" "/*.txt"
```

Do use double quotes for both arguments.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid having to write anything, try the [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/). The interface can be quite scary at first but just have a play around with it and you'll see it's not actually hard to use at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just if anyone needs in future:
I use 1-4 rename. It is fast, **does not have to be installed**. When you run it hit F2 for advanced mode and you can tell it to kill the first 4 characters. Below is the link to the program.

Download Link: http://www.1-4a.com/rename/

Answer (score 1):

in 2020 I had the same bulk rename problem: Remove fixed string of random characters for a lot of names.

Used this code in the Command Promt:

```
Rename "?????*.*" "*/////*.*"
```

(Remove any 5 characters) (You have tu  use ")

Work perfet, thanks guys from de past.