# Rename folder of files from epoch (unix time) to month-day-year-hour-minute-second?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder full of recordings which all read: " rec.(unixtime).mp3 "

ex: "rec.1447666687584.mp3" ideally turns into something like "10-16-2015_01-38-07.mp3"

I need to convert these filenames pretty regularly so I'm assuming writing a bat file is the best way to do this.

it seems easy enough to remove the first three characters as seen over here [How can I remove the first character from all filenames in a folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/273215/how-can-i-remove-the-first-character-from-all-filenames-in-a-folder)

and the mathematics for converting from epoch to days seems straightfoward as well ((((epochtimevalue/1000)/60)/60)/24) + the date 1/1/1970.

Does anyone have a straightforward solution for converting filenames like this?

Comment: Your math is wrong. You don't say what time zone you are in, but the GMT value for that epoch time is 11-16-2015_04-38-07.

Comment: Doh! - my mistake. I accidentally posted the U.S. Eastern standard time (GMT - 5:00) equivalent. The GMT time is 11-16-2015_09-38-07

Answer (score 1):

My [JREN.BAT regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081) is perfect for this problem. It is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is built into the script, and can be reached by executing `jren /?` (or `jren /??` if you want paged help).

JREN.BAT allows you to match and rename files using regular expressions, and the replacement string can be a JScript expression. Built into the utility is a sophisticated timestamp formatting function that makes the job really easy.

The following one liner will rename all "rec.EpochTime.mp3" files in the current directory to
"MM-DD-YYYY_hh-mm-ss.mp3" format. It will convert the epoch time using your local time zone. There are additional options that allow you to specify a specific time zone for the output.

```
jren "^rec\.(\d+)\.mp3$" "ts({dt:$1,fmt:'{mm}-{dd}-{yyyy}_{hh}-{nn}-{ss}.mp3'})" /j
```

But I strongly advise that you change the date format from MM-DD-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD instead. This allows you to easily sort your directory listings chronologically. The `{iso-dt}` format is shorthand for `{yyyy}-{mm}-{dd}`.

```
jren "^rec\.(\d+)\.mp3$" "ts({dt:$1,fmt:'{iso-dt}_{hh}-{nn}-{ss}.mp3'})" /j
```

Given that JREN is itself a batch script, you should use CALL JREN if you put the command within another batch script.